# What is the standard API Security practices for Restrict parameter sending through URL?

Tags: rest, security, post, get

From the security perspective, few people say that don't allow to use GET method in API to send query parameters through URLs like below format.

```
GET my-server/api/payment/checkDue?clientCode=123&monthYear=01022023
```

They also recommend using the POST method instead of the GET method in the API like below format.

```
POST `my-server/service/function { clientCode: 123, monthYear: 01022023}`
```

Can anyone suggest to me the best practices and the security flaws in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

From a security perspective, the advice to use the `POST` method instead of the `GET` method for sending query parameters through URLs is generally considered a good practice.

Best Practices:

1. Use `POST` for sensitive data: `POST` requests are typically used for operations that modify or create data on the server.
2. Avoid exposing sensitive data in URLs: Query parameters in URLs are often logged in various places, such as web server logs, proxies, or browser history. If you pass sensitive data through query parameters in a `GET` request, it can be easily visible and potentially exposed to unauthorized parties.
3. Prevent caching and bookmarking: `GET` requests with query parameters are often cached by web browsers, and users can bookmark them. This can lead to unintended exposure of sensitive data or potential security vulnerabilities if the URLs are shared or cached.

Security Flaws:

1. Lack of encryption: Both `GET` and `POST` requests can be intercepted during transmission unless appropriate encryption mechanisms like HTTPS are implemented. Without encryption, an attacker can potentially eavesdrop on the request and obtain sensitive data.
2. Inadequate input validation: Regardless of whether you use `GET` or `POST`, it is crucial to validate and sanitize the input parameters on the server side. Failure to do so can lead to security vulnerabilities such as `SQL` injection or cross-site scripting (`XSS`) attacks.
3. Lack of authentication and authorization: Merely switching from `GET` to POST does not address authentication and authorization concerns.
4. Limited cache control: While using `POST` requests can help prevent caching at the client-side, server-side caching or intermediate proxy caching can still occur. It is essential to implement cache-control headers or mechanisms to ensure that sensitive data is not cached or stored inappropriately.

Overall, while using `POST` instead of `GET` for sending query parameters can enhance security.

Additional links on this topic:

1. https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/
2. https://www.keycdn.com/support/put-vs-post
3. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html